# Why won't the InterpolationOrder function properly?

Tags: graphics3d, interpolation

```
data1 = {{0, 0, 1738.946},
   {0, 24, 1700.418},
   {0, 48, 1698.078},
   {32.05, 0, 1772.551},
   {32.05, 24, 1736.689},
   {32.05, 48, 1722.127},
   {64.10, 0, 1999.362},
   {64.10, 24, 1969.550},
   {64.10, 48, 1919.607}};

plot1a = ListPointPlot3D[data1, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[.05]]];

plot1b = ListPlot3D[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 2, BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> None];

Show[plot1a, plot1b]
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you tell us a bit more. For instance, what is wrong with the result you obtain? What would you like to obtain instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `InterpolationOrder -> 2` isn't working for you, but here is a work-around you might use.

```
data = {{0, 0, 1738.946}, {0, 24, 1700.418}, {0, 48, 
    1698.078}, {32.05, 0, 1772.551}, {32.05, 24, 1736.689}, {32.05, 
    48, 1722.127}, {64.10, 0, 1999.362}, {64.10, 24, 
    1969.550}, {64.10, 48, 1919.607}};

plot1a = 
  ListPointPlot3D[data, 
    BoxRatios -> 1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[.05]]];

iF = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

plot1b = 
  Plot3D[iF[x, y], {x, 0, 65}, {y, 0, 48}, BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> None];

Show[plot1a, plot1b]
```

[image: plot]

However, I think the plot would look better with small spheres in place of the 2D points you used to show the mesh. So I would use

```
plot1c = 
  With[{span = 2000 - 1700}, 
    Graphics3D[
      {GrayLevel[0.6], Ellipsoid[#, 10 {64/span, 48/span, 1}] & /@ data}, 
      BoxRatios -> 1]]

Show[plot1c, plot1b]
```

[image: plot]